# Is is possible to apply this data-frame transform?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, transform

Turn this data-frame :

```
  Name  │  car
  ──────┼────────      
  John  │  Volvo      
  John  │  Fiat      
  Paul  │  Dacia
```

Into this? :

```
  Name  │  car_1  │   car_2  
  ──────┼─────────┼─────────
  John  │  Volvo  │   Fiat    
  Paul  │  Dacia  │   NaN
```

for an arbitrary number of duplicates (arbitrary number of cars a person ) IDs in the first table.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: different versions of unstack and pivot would put the car brand on top (not what's needed).

Answer (score 2):

By using `unstack`

```
df1=df1.assign(numer=df1.groupby('Name').cumcount()).set_index(['Name','numer']).unstack()
df1
Out[256]: 
         car      
numer      0     1
Name              
John   Volvo  Fiat
Paul   Dacia  None

df1.columns=df1.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
df1
Out[261]: 
       car_0  car_1
Name             
John  Volvo  Fiat
Paul  Dacia  None
```

Comment: `df.set_index(['Name',df.groupby('Name').cumcount()+1]).unstack()['car'].add_prefix('car_')`

Comment: @ScottBoston much better than mine :-)

Comment: I've noticed, there is value in not always rushing for points.  Analyzing other solutions often lead to more optimal code.  Thank you for letting me comment.

Comment: @ScottBoston Nice point!:-) I think I need to slowing down as well :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
In [190]: (df.assign(x=df.groupby('Name').cumcount()+1)
     ...:    .pivot(index='Name', columns='x', values='car')
     ...:    .add_prefix('car_')
     ...:    .reset_index()
     ...:    .rename_axis(None,1))
     ...:
Out[190]:
   Name  car_1 car_2
0  John  Volvo  Fiat
1  Paul  Dacia  None
```